# How to add two list in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

My custom class like this, allList elements below

```
 public class Product(){
     Short code1;
     Short code2;
     Short code3;
     Short code4;
     Short code5;
 }

 List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
 List<Short> allList= new ArrayList<>();

 allList elements:
 42,0,0,0,0
 31,0,0,0,0
 1,2,0,0,0
 3,5,6,0,0
 42,0,0,0,0
 31,0,0,0,0
```

My code:

```
 for(Product item: productList ){
    List<Short> product = new ArrayList<>();
     //some code  to delete zeros
     if(item.getCode1 > 0){
        product.add(item.getCode1());
     }

     allList.addAll(product);
 }
```

this is the result when I use addall:

```
[42,31,1,2,3,5,6,42,31]
```

but this is the result I want:

```
[42,31,[1,2],[3,5,6],42,31]
```

Comment: How should that work? Your list elements are `Short`s, not lists themself. Also, what are the rules to assemble some elements in a sub-list?

Comment: You have 2 different types in your `List`, is it what you want?

Something like `[[42],[31],[1,2],[3,5,6],[42],[31]]` could work for you?

Comment: It looks like you're storing allList as a List<Short> when what you really want is a List<List<Short>>. Could we see how you're adding those initial elements to allList?

Comment: sory allList type it was wrong. allList custom Class

Comment: @ThomasPoignant yes i want it

Comment: using two dimensional arraylist , I solved my problem.